# Versioning Practices for Javascript SPA Application

Tags: javascript, deployment

I've developed an SPA using AureliaJS. We use team Foundation server to service our source control, but that doesn't really help with good versioning practices. For instance, with our WPF applications, we run a server build that adds a new build folder with a new version. This is helpful obviously because if we change something in a new build that completely screws the application up, we always have fallbacks. Since the only files I have in the SPA is an index.html and 3 or 4 Javascript files,  what should I be doing to version these "builds"? I've been running a build via the command line, which really isn't a build - it just compiles the minified js files. After I compile, I've been creating a new folder with a version number and copying the new files over.  I feel like there's a better way to do this. What is industry standard for this?